# TypeError: {array of objects).map is not a function - Typescript + React issue, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm working on a personal blog using Nextjs.
There are two pages which render posts:

1. Homepage - where I render a select few featured posts
2. Posts - where all posts are rendered

I'm using dummy data, here is my PostUtils.tsx file:

```
export interface PostThumbnailProps {
  id: string,
  title: string,
  description: string,
  imageSrc: string,
  postDate: Date
}

export const posts: PostThumbnailProps[] = [
  {
    title: 'First Post',
    description: 'This is a description for the post',
    imageSrc: 'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2022/day-of-the-dead-2022-6753651837109655.2-l.webp',
    postDate: new Date(),
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    title: 'Second Post',
    description: 'This is another description for the post',
    imageSrc: 'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2022/day-of-the-dead-2022-6753651837109655.2-l.webp',
    postDate: new Date(),
    id: '2'
  },
  {
    title: 'Third Post',
    description: 'This is another description for the post',
    imageSrc: 'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2022/day-of-the-dead-2022-6753651837109655.2-l.webp',
    postDate: new Date(),
    id: '3'
  },
  {
    title: 'Fourth Post',
    description: 'This is another description for the post',
    imageSrc: 'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2022/day-of-the-dead-2022-6753651837109655.2-l.webp',
    postDate: new Date(),
    id: '4'
  }
];
```

Here's my Homepage:

```
import PostsGrid from "./PostsGrid";
import { posts } from "./PostUtils";

export default function FeaturedPosts() {

  const renderPosts = posts.slice(0, 3);

  return (
    <div className='container bg-gray-200 p-8 my-10 rounded-xl shadow'>
      <PostsGrid posts={renderPosts} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here's the Posts page:

```
import PostsGrid from '../../components/Posts/PostsGrid'
import { posts } from '../../components/Posts/PostUtils'

export default function AllPosts() {

  return (
    <>
      <div className='container mx-auto bg-gray-200 p-8 my-10 rounded-xl shadow'>
        <div className='mb-7 text-center'>
          <h1 className='font-bold text-4xl'>All My Posts</h1>
          <time className='italic text-sm'>Last updated: November 5th, 2022</time>
        </div>
        <PostsGrid posts={posts} />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

And finally the PostsGrid:

```
import PostThumbnail, { PostThumbnailProps } from "./PostThumbnail";

export default function PostsGrid(posts: PostThumbnailProps[]) {

  console.log('posts are', posts)

  return (
    <ul className="grid sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-5">
      {posts.map((post: PostThumbnailProps) =>
        <PostThumbnail
          key={post.id}
          post={post}
        />
      )}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
TypeError: posts.map is not a function

components/Posts/PostsGrid.tsx (9:13) @ PostsGrid

   7 | return (
   8 |   <ul className="grid sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-5">
>  9 |     {posts.map((post: PostThumbnailProps) =>
     |           ^
  10 |       <PostThumbnail
  11 |         key={post.id}
  12 |         post={post}
```

I declared my posts as an array of objects using the PostThumbnailProps interface - why isn't "map" available to me?

Here's another error that I'm not entirely sure what it means:

```
"Type '{ posts: PostThumbnailProps[]; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PostThumbnailProps[]'. Property 'posts' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PostThumbnailProps[]'.
```

I tried declaring the array with `Array<PostThumbnailProps>`, but that didn't change anything.
After logging the `typeof posts`, I get the value "object", so it's obviously picking it up as an object rather than an array of objects.

Answer (score 4):

Components take single parameter which is an object with props

```
export default function PostsGrid({ posts }: { posts: PostThumbnailProps[] }) {
  // ...
}
```